# how to get session id from cookie jar in perl?

Tags: perl

My question is very simple.. It is how to get session id from cookie jar ... I have tried below code :-

```
use warnings;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
if ( !$ua ) {
    print "Can not get the page :UserAgent fialed \n";
    return 0;
}

my $cookies = new HTTP::Cookies( file => './cookies.dat', autosave => 1 );
$ua->cookie_jar($cookies);

# push does all magic to exrtact cookies and add to header for further reqs. useragent should be newer
push @{ $ua->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';
$result = $ua->request(
    POST "URL",
    {   Username => 'admin',
        Password => 'admin',
        Submit   => 'Submit',
    }
);
my $session_id = $cookies->extract_cookies($result);
print $session_id->content;
print "\n\n";
$resp = $result->content;
#print "Result is \n\n\n $resp \n";
$anotherURI    = URL;
$requestObject = HTTP::Request::Common::GET $anotherURI;
$result        = $ua->request($requestObject);
$resp          = $result->content;
#print $resp."\n";
```

I am not getting where the session id is stored and how to fetch it ?
Note:- URL contains the URL of the page.

Comment: You should always `use strict` in all your Perl programs. This looks like you copied it from somewhere on the internet (a very old ressource) and you're not entirely sure what you are doing. It would be helpful to know the URL in order to help you. The session id is probably in that cookies.dat file somewhere. You can also take a look at what the cookie is called by using Firebug or Chrome's devtools to inspect the HTTP response of the website.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [HTTP::CookieMonster](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::CookieMonster) to make this kind of thing a bit easier.  If you don't know which cookie you're looking for, you can do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::CookieMonster;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech    = WWW::Mechanize->new;
my $monster = HTTP::CookieMonster->new( $mech->cookie_jar );

my $url = 'http://www.nytimes.com';
$mech->get( $url );

my @all_cookies = $monster->all_cookies;
foreach my $cookie ( @all_cookies ) {
    printf( "key: %s value: %s\n", $cookie->key, $cookie->val);
}
```

If you already know the cookie's key, you can something like:

```
my $cookie = $monster->get_cookie('RMID');
my $session_id = $cookie->val;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [HTTP::Cookies->scan](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookies#cookie_jar-scan-callback).

Something like this should do the trick (should add a constraint on the domain at least):

```
my $session_id;
$cookie_jar->scan(
    sub {
        my ($key,       $val,    $path,    $domain,  $port,
            $path_spec, $secure, $expires, $discard, $hash
        ) = @_;

        if ( $key eq "session_id" ) {
            $session_id = $val;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: i am getting an error in this code like "Use of uninitialized calue $session_id". Can you please tell me where does this $cookie_jar came from ? Because i had not used it in my code snippet. Can you please  write the code again or explain it!!!

Comment: The $cookie_jar is $cookie in your code (the instance of HTTP::Cookies). I feel like you do not understand your code, you should poke around a bit more in order to understand what you are doing before going further.